# php odbc_connect to access mdb file another server

Tags: php, odbc

Can any one help me how to put parameters in `odbc_connect()` using php to connect a database *.mdb driver on another server.

```
$conn=odbc_connect('','','');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Example for odbc connection](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.odbc-connect.php)`

```
<?php
// Microsoft SQL Server utilise le pilote SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver : 
// il permet les connexions à SQL 7, 2000, 2005 et 2008
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

// Microsoft Access
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

// Microsoft Excel
$excelFile = realpath('C:/ExcelData.xls');
$excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
?>`
```

Comment: Ok, it's good on local xampp. but how can I use it when the website is online and the file on another server?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the mdb file on a share on the server and access it that way but there are limitations doing that. You can get yourself an ODBC-ODBC Bridge and that allows connection to any remote ODBC data source so long as you can install something on the server.